# What will be the width and height of a mock up in an html template in themeforest?

Tags: html, templates, mockups

Is there any specific **width** and **height** of a mock up in an html template in themeforest?
One of my template has big mock up size. One said that the mock up size should be small.
Is there any specific **width** and **height** of a mock up in an html template in themeforest?